# How to store a string array so that it can be referenced later?

Tags: c

```
   int counter = 0; 
   while(1) {
      char *arr[9];
      // performing string parsing, results will be put into arr
      counter++;
    }
```

Suppose in the loop I declare a string array, and the program will perform some parsing, and the results will be stored into the array. Next time, this process happens again, so the content in the array would be wiped out.

How can I store the content of the array, so that later I can reference the array in the program doing this: `history[counter] // the content should be arr at that point of execution`

Comment: Move the declaration before the loop?

Comment: @Gene, suppose inside the loop, there will be actions performed based on the current arr content

Comment: Use something like `char ***history` to hold the past array of strings. Initially allocate space for some random number of elements(say n) and in the `while` loop if the number exceeds n, `realloc()`